# how to publish real robot-arm joint_states by ROS

Tags: joint-state-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I have a real six-dof robot arm and it's urdf model, the urdf model can display well in rviz.
Now I want to publish robot's joint_states so the rviz can show out the real robot pose.
But I find that joint_state_publisher node will also publish joint_states topic, and the node is need when visual urdf in rviz, so I  don't know how to resolve the conflict between my own node and joint_state_publisher node, thanks for some tips!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246553/how-to-publish-real-robot-arm-joint_states-by-ros/) by [yin](https://answers.ros.org/users/25699/yin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2016-10-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looks like a duplicate of [How to visualize a real robot in Rviz](http://answers.ros.org/question/243984), but just to reiterate:

If you have a node that already publishes joint states for your real robot, then you don't need to start `joint_state_publisher`.

An instance of `joint_state_publisher` is only needed if:

1. you don't have another node that publishes `JointState` messages and you want to fake them (`use_gui:=true`)
2. you have multiple publishers of `JointState` messages and want to aggregate them (`source_list:=[..]`)

> [..] I don't know how to resolve the conflict between my own node and joint_state_publisher node [..]

Just don't start `joint_state_publisher` (but see the points above).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yin](https://answers.ros.org/users/25699/yin/) on 2016-10-27**:
Ok, that's it, just not start joint_state_publisher will ok, thank you!